# Can API.ai/ RASA NLU be integrated with Tensorflow to make a chatbot

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, chatbot, dialogflow-es, rasa-nlu

Below are the questions which are making me confused . Hope friends here will clear it.

1. Both Api.ai and RASA NLU are libraries used for Natural Language Processing and Natural Language Generation ? Am i right
2. Can we do NLU in Tensorflow so that we can perform all NLU + ML operations in Tensorflow itself?
3. If i use Api.ai or RASA NLU for NLU purpose and how do i perform ML Operations with Api.ai or RASA NLU ? Can we build our own ML model and make it work with Api.ai or RASA NLU

Scenario

Suppose i just want to build a chat bot .

1. I use API.ai or RASA NLU for NLU i.e to break input into intents and entities.
2. Now i have to create my own ML model to train some sets of data which i will create using Tensor flow.
3. How can i integrate these two to make it powerful ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As has been mentioned RASA NLU is a library and Api.AI is a service.

2) YES! RASA now supports using TensorFlow as part of the pipeline.

3) One of the nice things about RASA is that it lets you use the same API as Api.ai (Now Dialogflow), so you can use the same training data for both. However, I think your MUCH better off sticking with RASA over a service like Dialogflow.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your specific questions:

1. No, Rasa NLU is a library; API.ai (now called Dialogflow) is a product, currently owned by Google. And neither does natural language generation. They mainly do Natural Language Understanding. For Rasa NLU this is restricted to just intents and entities classification. Dialogflow also includes things like context, web hooks, etc. To get more functionality with Rasa you will want to look into [Rasa Core](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core) as well.
2. There are certainly [people](https://github.com/HadoopIt/rnn-nlu) doing NLU with tensorflow. Rasa NLU doesn't use it and I don't know if we know exactly how Dialogflow works.
3. The whole point in using something like Rasa NLU or Dialoflow is to abstract away alot of the knowledge necessary of how the ML works. If you want to implement your own classifier then see the link above for tensorflow or look into [MITIE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwie6p7np8zXAhUCOiYKHaxwDKIQFgg8MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmit-nlp%2FMITIE&usg=AOvVaw3fnSYeqU4qlog1ZMwAtbPP) or [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/examples) and sklearn, which are the two backends that Rasa packages up.

Hopefully that clears up the questions. To consolidate your scenario given, no additional ML is needed if you use Rasa or DialogFlow. They do that under their own respective hoods.

- Dialogflow packages everything you need for a complete chatbot solution.
- Rasa NLU can be used together with Botkit or Rasa Core for a complete chatbot solution.